# Long expression crashes SymPy

Tags: python-3.x, expression, sympy

I'm using 64-bit Python 3.3.1, pylab and 32GB system RAM. This function:

```
def sqrt2Expansion(limit):
    x    = Symbol('x')
    term = 1+1/x
    for _ in range(limit):
        term = term.subs({x: (2+1/x)})
    return term.subs({x: 2})
```

Produces expressions of this kind: `1 + 1/(2 + 1/(2 + 1/(2 + 1/(2 + 1/(2 + 1/(...))))))`.
When called as: `sqrt2Expansion(100)` returns valid result, but `sqrt2Expansion(200)` produces `RuntimeError` with many pages of traceback and hangs up pylab/IPython interpreter with plenty of system memory left unused. Any ideas how to implement it more efficiently? I would like to call `sqrt2Expansion(1000)` and still get a result.

Comment: Changing `term = term.subs({x: (2+1/x)})` to `term = term.subs({x: (2+1/x)}).factor()` should do the trick. Could you explain the purpose of what you are doing?

Comment: @Krastanov Thank you, it does indeed work for `sqrt2Expansion(1000)`. My purpose was to learn SymPy while solving [Euler problem 57](http://projecteuler.net/problem=57) in this case. I know of more elegant solutions, but I wanted to see, if brute force would work in this case. If you care to post your comment as an answer I will upvote it and choose it as an accepted answer.

Comment: I tried to answer more extensively below. I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to elaborate on the comment that I have posted above.

Sympy expressions are trees. Each operation is a node which has as branches its operands. For instance `x+y` looks like `Add(x, y)` and `x*(y+z)` like `Mul(x, Add(y, z))`.

Usually these expressions get automatically flattened like in `Add(x, Add(y, z))` becoming `Add(x, y, z)`, but for more complicated cases one can get very deep trees.

And deep trees can pose problems especially when either the interpreter or the library itself limits the depth of permitted recursion (as a protection against infinite recursion and exploding memory usage). Most probably this is the cause of your `RuntimeError`: each `subs` makes the tree deeper and as the tree gets deeper the recursive `subs` must call itself more times till it gets to the deepest node.

You can simplify the tree to something of the form `polynomial/polynomial` which has constant depth by using the `factor` method. Just change `term = term.subs({x: (2+1/x)})` to `term = term.subs({x: (2+1/x)}).factor()`.

Comment: I was suspecting the depth of recursion being a problem, but it would be nice if SymPy produced appropriate error message instead of just hanging up. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I think (I might be wrong) that this error is controlled by the interpreter and that it is generally hard to catch in code (it is not SymPy that executes `raise RuntimeError`). So SymPy does not have much control over the message. On the other hand if some volunteer refactors slightly `subs` so it does not use recursion, the error and limitation will go away.

Comment: `cancel` will be more efficient than factor. If you aren't worried about canceling out common factors, `expr.as_numer_denom` is the most efficient, but it can lead to very large expression growth in some cases.

Comment: @asmeurer I timed a version with `cancel` and it runs in 66% of the time `factor` version takes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you need to do it symbolically? Just start with 2 and work from there. You will never hit recursion errors because the fraction will be flattened at each stage

```
In [10]: def sqrt2(limit):
   ....:     expr = Rational(1, 2)
   ....:     for i in range(limit):
   ....:         expr = 1/(2 + expr)
   ....:     return 1 + expr
   ....:

In [11]: sqrt2(100)
Out[11]:
552191743651117350907374866615429308899
───────────────────────────────────────
390458526450928779826062879981346977190

In [12]: sqrt2(100).evalf()
Out[12]: 1.41421356237310

In [13]: sqrt(2).evalf()
Out[13]: 1.41421356237310

In [15]: print sqrt2(1000)
173862817361510048113392732063287518809190824104684245763570072944177841306522186007881248757647526155598965224342185265607829530599877063992267115274300302346065892232737657351612082318884085720085755135975481584205200521472790368849847501114423133808690827279667023048950325351004049478273731369644053281603356987998498457434883570613383878936628838144874794543267245536801570068899/122939577152521961584762100253767379068957010866562498780385985503882964809611193975682098617378531179669585936977443997763999765977165585582873799618452910919591841027248057559735534272951945685362378851460989224784933532517808336113862600995844634542449976278852113745996406252046638163909206307472156724372191132577490597501908825040117098606797865940229949194369495682751575387690
```

Comment: Since you are solving that Project Euler problem, you probably will want to modify the algorithm to check the result at each stage, rather than recomputing the whole thing 1000 times (though honestly, even doing it that way will finish in a few seconds).

Comment: What imports do I need for `Rational`?

Comment: I replaced `Rational` with `Fraction` to make it work in Python 3.3. Yours is the most elegant declarative solution I've seen so far. I started in this direction, but I got stuck - I'm a Python newbie. I played with SymPy mainly for future applications - I know it is an overkill for this problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Rational is coming from SymPy. Fraction works just as well in this problem too (though you don't get the nice 2D pretty printing with it :).

Comment: And SymPy works fine in python 3 (you have to download the python 3 version).